# Return only one record with column indicator from an array in VBA

Tags: vba

The following code steps through every cell to check for <> 0 in this array (I specifically don't want to sum). How can I limit output to just list the column letters where this occurs at least once.

```
Dim Arr1() As Variant
Dim num_rows As Long, num_columns As Long
Dim column_num As Long, row_num As Long
Dim strTieOutMsg As String
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out").Select
    Arr1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out").Range("B15:CG66").Value
    num_columns = UBound(Arr1, 2)
    num_rows = UBound(Arr1, 1)
    For column_num = 1 To num_columns
        For row_num = 1 To num_rows
            If Abs(Arr1(row_num, column_num)) > 0.0001 Then
                strTieOutMsg = strTieOutMsg & Chr(13) & "Failure"
            End If
            Next row_num
            Next column_num
        End With
        Debug.Print (strTieOutMsg)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to store the column value in an Array?

Comment: @DavidG. Only 1 day into learning VBA so not sure what you mean :) Each column has 51 values so what are you referencing to store?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using an array, so you can declare a different array to store the columns. I will use part of your code.

First, declare another array:

```
Dim Columns (0) as Integer
```

Using your code:

```
If Abs(Arr1(row_num, column_num)) > 0.0001 Then
    strTieOutMsg = strTieOutMsg & Chr(13) & "Failure"
    'Increase your Columns array
     ReDim Columns (ubound(arr, 1) + 1)
    'Store the colum_num in your Columns Array
    Columns (ubound(arr, 1)) = column_num
End If
```

This way your columns values are being stored in `Columns` Array.